# How to recover from bad mythtv frontend settings

Tags: mythtv

I have screwed up my display settings and now when frontend starts the display is HUGE so that only part of each menu is visible and the screen is not scrollable.

Is there a file to delete, or perhaps a startup option that would force frontend to start as if no previous customization had occurred?  A fresh start?

Thank you in advance for any info or ideas.

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

All you should need to do is run this command in a terminal:
`mythfrontend --reset`